# Unexpected token at JSON position

Tags: javascript, json

When using JSON.parse to achieve the output expected I am getting error `Unexpected token B in JSON at position 1`. What is it I am missing?

```js
var string1 = "BODEBO,CARNE";
var array1 = string1.split(',');
var string2 = "1,2";
var array2 = string2.split(',');


var a =[]; var b = [];
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
    var c = array1[i];
    var d = array2[i];
    e = "[" +  c +","+d +"]";
    e =JSON.parse(e);
    a.push(e);
}

console.log(a);
```

Ouptput Expected

```
[[ 'BODEBO', '1'],[ 'CARNE','2' ]];
```

without json.parse

OUTPUT

```
 [ '[BODEBO,1]', '[CARNE,2]' ]
```

I dont want '  ' on each array element

Comment: Expected output is not a JSON is an array of arrays....

Comment: There's no need for `JSON.parse()` at all in your code. If you want those elements in an array, you can do it in one statement.

Comment: JSON.parse can only parse JSON, what you have is a two-dimensional array

Comment: `a = [[array1[0], array2[0]], [array1[1], array2[1]]];`

Comment: Besides all that, strings in JSON must have double-quotes. Single-quotes are not valid.

Comment: try with `a.push([c, d]);` instead of using your `e` var and JSON

Comment: if i dont do JSON.parse i get [ '[BODEBO,1]', '[CARNE,2]' ]
I dont want ' ' on each array elemen @Pointy

Comment: Don't build a string like you're doing; just put the strings directly into the arrays.

Comment: Depending on your situation you maybe want to ensure that `array1` and `array2` have the same length.

Answer (score 3):

Might as well just make an array if the output expected has arrays.

```js
var string1 = "BODEBO,CARNE";
var array1 = string1.split(',');
var string2 = "1,2";
var array2 = string2.split(',');

var a = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    a.push([array1[i], array2[i]]);
}

console.log(a);
```

But who needs loops when you have map?

```js
var string1 = "BODEBO,CARNE";
var array1 = string1.split(',');
var string2 = "1,2";
var array2 = string2.split(',');

console.log(array1.map((s, idx) => [s,array2[idx]]));
```

Comment: He doesn't want a JSON string, he just wants an array.

Comment: You wouldn't need var b any more using this solution

Answer (score 2):

You could simply loop over the first array, and then push a single array onto your output array.

```
var string1 = "BODEBO,CARNE";
var array1 = string1.split(',');
var string2 = "1,2";
var array2 = string2.split(',');

var a = [];

for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
    a.push([ array1[i], array2[i] ]);
}

// You can now just make use of the 'a' array.
console.log(a);
```

Giving you the following output: [["BODEBO","1"],["CARNE","2"]]

Comment: He doesn't want a JSON string, he just wants an array.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated my code and explained the results in comments.

Answer (score -1):

In order for `JSON.parse` to work you need to provide valid JSON. The function is currently passing in an array like:

```
[BODEBO,1]
```

which is not valid. To make it work you need to wrap each item in quotes, like:

```
["BODEBO","1"]
```

```js
var string1 = "BODEBO,CARNE";
var array1 = string1.split(',');
var string2 = "1,2";
var array2 = string2.split(',');


var a = [];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var c = array1[i];
  var d = array2[i];
  e = "[\"" + c + "\",\"" + d + "\"]";
  e = JSON.parse(e);
  a.push(e);
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: That has some security flaws if the string contains any quotes. JSON is not required or useful for converting JS arrays.